# Has anybody seen matplotlib leaking filehandles (Vera.ttf) on Windows 7 with version 1.0.1?

Tags: matplotlib

I create many plots that are saved using pylab.savefig and observe that the Python process ends up with hundreds of filehandles for C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\Vera.ttf.  Eventually this crashes the process due to too many filehandles (at which point there are over 700 handles to Vera.ttf as viewed via "Process Explorer").

I see several references to old leaks in matplotlib in the archives but as far as I can tell they were supposed to be resolved by version 1.0.1.

In my code I repeatedly call pylab.close("all") as well as pylab.close(figure_variable) and figure_variable.clear() in an attempt to get matplotlib to free resources.

For reference, I'm using the latest release of Enthought python distribution for 64-bit Windows.  I can duplicate the problem by something like:

```
for i in range(1000):
    fig = pylab.figure()
    pylab.plot(some_data)
    fig.savefig(filename)
    fig.clear()
    pylab.close(fig)
    if i % 10 == 1: pylab.close("all")
```

Does anybody know how to get matplotlib to either release the handle on Vera.ttf or avoid reloading the same file so many times?  From what I observe in Process Explorer it's actually creating multiple handles per plot.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I can't reproduce the behavior on linux... `lsof` reports 97 open file handles for the process, and this doesn't change as it runs. (Of course, that doesn't mean that it isn't broken on Windows!) You might want to file a bug report and/or ask on the mailing list.

Comment: Interestingly, I tried on another Windows PC w/Home rather than Professional that has a 32-bit version of Python 2.6 but also has matplotlib 1.0.1.  There I see many copies of Vera.ttf but the amount does not keep growing and each plot seems to create 4-5 new handles but then close all of them.  On the Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit Python 2.7 the same code seems to create 4-5 handles but only close 1-2 of them (hard to tell in the flickering of Process Explorer exactly what's happening) until it eventually crashes.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of pending pull requests to address this issue, one of which will make it into Matplotlib v1.1.1 (the next stable release): see [#795](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/795) and [#798](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/798) for the two alternatives, and participate in [#791](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/791) which is the topic for v1.1.1 release candidate testing.

A fix like the one proposed in [#795](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/795) was applied to the git master branch 7 months ago, so if you're on that, you shouldn't be seeing this issue anymore. The only caveat there is that it uses the `with` statement, so won't work on Python < 2.6